# Pass nested properties in asp.net mvc actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My action accepts a model that looks like the following:

```
public class ClassListVM
{
    public ClassListVM()
    {
        Filter = new ClassFilterModel();
    }

    public ClassFilterModel Filter { get; set; }
    public PagedList<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}

public class ClassFilterModel
{
    public int? TermId { get; set; }
    public int? SubFormId { get; set; }
    public int? FormId { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index(ClassListVM model)
{
    model.Classes = classService.GetClasses(model.Filter);
    return View(model);
}
```

Now I want to generate a url like this: `/Classes?Filter.SubFormId=1`. How do I get the `Filter` part into the url using this code:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Classes", new {Filter.TermId = Model.TermId, Filter.SubFormId = subForm.SubFormId})">go</a>
```

As you can see, `Filter` cannot be used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, you can build it this way:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Classes")?Filter.TermId=@Model.TermId&amp;Filter.SubFormId=@subForm.SubFormId">go</a>
```

Something like that; essentially, embed the query string into the client markup, and inject in only the parameters.

Comment: I ended up doing this, I hope there is a better way to do it though

Comment: Maybe using a dictionary for the attributes, instead of the anonymous classes.  Anonymous classes can't support dot notation (as in Filter.TermId) in that fashion.  A dictionary could using new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Filter.TermId", Model.TermId }}.  You could try that.